# Laravel HTTP Client Pool Error Handling Without Calling onRejected

Tags: php, laravel, http

I'm trying to catch all possible exceptions in code below.
The question is, are there any exception types that this code does not handle?

```
/*
 *
 * This is just an EXAMPLE code
 *
 */
    
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
    
$users = User::all();
    
$website = "https://www.google.com/";
Http::pool(function (Pool $pool) use ($users, $website) {
    $users->each(function ($user) use ($pool, $website) {
        $pool->retry(1)
            ->timeout(60)
            ->get($website)
            ->then(function ($response) use ($user) {
                // On Fulfilled
    
                $status = 
                    !(($response instanceof Exception || $response->getStatusCode() !== 200));
    
                $user->status = $status;
                $user->save();
            });
    });
});
```